# SQL - How to get the Year-Week using the ISO weeks?

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, calendar

I would like to get a year number - week number (f.i. 2021-01) using the ISO weeks count.
I did manage to get both of them seperate using the following code:

**IsoWeek:**

```
(datepart(ISOWK, [Date]))
```

**IsoYearNumber:**

```
YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, [Date]), [Date]))
```

However, when I try to combine them into the YYYY-WW format using the line below I will get strange values like 2073 for 2020 WK 53.

```
(YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, [Date]), [Date]))) + '-' + (datepart(ISOWK, [Date]))
```

What should I change in the line above to get the ISO Year and Week in the YYYY-WW format?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CONCAT` function. `+` is *both* the [addition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [concatenation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in T-SQL; which is it inferred to be depends on the data that surrounds it. Here it is being inferred as a plus operator, not a concatenation operator, as the data in the query are `int` values, and the `'-'` is therefore being implicitly converted to an `int` too (`'-'` as an `int` is `0`).

If we use the current date we have the expression below:

```sql
(YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, '20211028'), '20211028'))) + '-' + (datepart(ISOWK, '20211028'))
```

Which returns `2064`. That's because it resolves to `2021 + '-' + 43 = 2021 + 0 + 43 = 2064`.

If you use `CONCAT` you get what you want, which implicitly converts each value to a string based data type first:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT((YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20211028'), '20211028'))), '-', (DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20211028')));
```

*I also make your casing consistent and use the same keyword for the date part, `ISOWEEK`, as you you inconsistently use `isoww` and `ISOWK`.*

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well!! Indeed the + was used as plus operator instead of a concatenation operator.